# shifting a load of Electric Vehicle to the next row if a condition is not fulfulled in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am making a scenario in excel where Electric vehicles are being charged in a given time range. i have a neighborhood loads and the load of EV at specific times. the cable capacity is 50 kW (means the combined load of EV and household should not exceed this value). is there a formula, which checks if the combined load of EV and household is below 50 kW, then leaves it unchanged. if it is more than 50KW then shifts the EV load to next row and checks for the condition again if satisfied it is less then 50kw it adds it here otherwise shift to the next row until the condition is satisfied.

I have attached the sample excel file for clarification. more text in the file explains the case

picture below shows the data in the Excel file
[EV scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLaVJ.jpg)

any help would be appreciated

Best,

EXCEL https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArYn8TW3_a3d3n6MbEjcWsfkdB3q

PIC https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArYn8TW3_a3d3wGtOdrpFzh_I8r3

Comment: You mean to say if Sum of EV+NELoad = 50 then Charged if < 50 then leave, if > 50 then move next? Since you have both values EV & NELoad in every row in that case what do u mean by Shift to next row? I can suggest you IF Function will check all 3 conditions , just confirm whether I'm getting it correct or not !!

Comment: @RajeshS; i uploaded 1 more pic maybe it clarifies what i am trying to say. so there is load against every time. i plug 1 car at 2:15 and the load stays constant till 2:45. now you can see the total load is >50 in row 4. now another car is plugged in at 2:30, now as the load is already >50 in row 4, the formula should not let this car to be plugged in at this time. it should be plugged in at row 6 where the total load does not increase 50 kw . hope this helps

Comment: What I've realized after considering the hand written data that You want the formula to say that the CAR can't be plugged if the NE Load is `>=50`. in that case in `C2` you write this one `=if(b2>=50,"Car Can't Plugged", Can Plugged")` & fill the formula down, you find for Row `2, 3, 4 & 6, 7` Can Plugged. Please confirm whether this helps you or not ?

Comment: @RajeshS, No rajesh, i want the formula to automatically adjust the load of the EV (where the combined load of NE and EV is >50 ) to the cell where it will not exceed 50. this is the concept of load shifting to hours where the electric grid is not loaded.

Comment: In that case you can test (NE+EV)>50, or if you simplify the mechanism of their combination then I can solve it for you.